# How to get matched aggregations based on UserId in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, aggregation-framework

I am working on sample application in react in that i used aggregations, i implemented a query based on userid matching the status getting the MAXDate and MINDate from it.How to get remaining fields based on the max and minimum fields.

```
    app.get('/varun', function (req, res) {
  Light.aggregate( [ 
      { 
      "$match" : {
             "STATUS":"LIGHTS OFF"} 
      },
        {
         "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$SWITCHID",
                    LIGHTOFFMINDATE: { "$min" : "$RECEIVEDDATE"
                                      },
                    LIGHTOFFMAXDATE:{"$max":"$RECEIVEDDATE"
                                    },
                    information:{"$push":
                    {
                      _id:"$SWITCHID",
                      TOTALSTREETLIGHTS:"$TOTALSTREETLIGHTS",
                      WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS:"$WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS",
                      CUMULATIVEKWH:"$CUMULATIVEKWH",
                      STATUS:"$STATUS",
                      LATITUDE:"$LATITUDE",
                      LONGITUDE:"$LONGITUDE",
                      OFFICE_ID:"$OFFICE_ID",
                      FLAG2:"$FLAG2",
                      CREATE_DATE:"$CREATE_DATE"

                    }
                  },
},

}]
, function (err, light) {

  console.log("naresh:" +JSON.stringify(light));


        res.json(light);
    });
});

output:-
"_id": "Z6-W66-9C/3",
        "LIGHTOFFMINDATE": "2018-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "LIGHTOFFMAXDATE": "2019-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
```

Here,i am placing the code with related output.can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `$sort` before the `$group` and use `$first` and `$last` with `$$ROOT` to access the whole document.

```
Light.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS OFF"}},
  {"$sort":{"RECEIVEDDATE":1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$SWITCHID",
    "LIGHTOFFMINDATE":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
    "LIGHTOFFMAXDATE":{"$last":"$$ROOT"}
  }}
],function (err, light) {
   console.log("naresh:" +JSON.stringify(light));
   res.json(light);
});
```

Get counts for min and max date

```
Light.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS OFF"}},
  {"$sort":{"RECEIVEDDATE":1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$SWITCHID",
    "LIGHTOFFMINDATEDOC":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
    "LIGHTOFFMAXDATEDOC":{"$last":"$$ROOT"},
    "ALLDOCS":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$project": {
    "LIGHTOFFMINDATEDOC": 1,
    "minSalary": 1,
    "LIGHTOFFMAXDATEDOC": 1,
    "LIGHTOFFMINDATECOUNT": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$ALLDOCS",
          "as": "doc",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$doc.RECEIVEDDATE",
              "$LIGHTOFFMINDATEDOC.RECEIVEDDATE"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "LIGHTOFFMAXDATECOUNT": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$ALLDOCS",
          "as": "doc",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$doc.RECEIVEDDATE",
              "$LIGHTOFFMAXDATEDOC.RECEIVEDDATE"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
],function (err, light) {
    console.log("naresh:" +JSON.stringify(light));
    res.json(light);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much  i will try this code server but not response

Comment: Oh I see the issue. I missed the callback. Updated answer.

Comment: i got it thank you very much Veeram sir , sir any possible status off and on one query

Comment: Np. Not sure I follow you. Do you want to add more status to check in the matching condition ? If yes Try `{"$match":{"STATUS":{$in:["LIGHTS OFF", "LIGHTS ON]"}}}`

Comment: ok i will try sir thank you so much sir ,sir one more question if any possible how many count in max and min date

Comment: Np. Added an update to count max and min dated rows.

Comment: thank you sir  ,  sir your mail Id plzzzzz   @Veeram